VueJS application not building
I am using node 16. For VueJS, I have received code from client and my code is not giving error but during npm run build, it is getting stuck and not showing any progress in terminal.
Here is my details:
package.json:
{
  "name": "admin",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "webpack",
    "watch": "concurrently \"webpack --watch\" \"npm:sass\"",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "sass": "sass --watch src/scss:assets/css",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.10.1",
    "axios": "^0.21.4",
    "concurrently": "^6.2.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "date-fns": "^2.22.1",
    "html-to-text": "^7.1.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "luxon": "^1.24.1",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "slugify": "^1.5.3",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-loader": "^15.9.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "vue2-editor": "^2.10.2",
    "vuedraggable": "^2.24.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.15",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "esm": "^3.2.25",
    "image-size": "^1.0.2",
    "kleur": "^4.1.5",
    "npm-watch": "^0.11.0",
    "prompts": "^2.4.2",
    "sass": "^1.35.1",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead",
    "IE 10-11"
  ]
}


webpack.config.js:
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader')
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  resolve: { alias: { vue: 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js' } },
  mode: 'production',
  entry: './src/admin-app.js',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  watch: true,
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        use: 'vue-loader'
      },
      {
         test:/\.(s*)css$/,
         use:['style-loader','css-loader']
     },
     {
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[name].[ext]',
              outputPath: 'dist/fonts/'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          'file-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        // Only run `.js` files through Babel
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
          }
        }
      },
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets/js/apps'),
    filename: 'admin-app.js'
  },
  optimization: {
      minimize: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new VueLoaderPlugin()
  ]
};


For information:
admin-app.js is at correct location.
Output in build:
> admin@0.1.0 build
> webpack


webpack is watching the files…

Hash: 8bfa1f8c53eb0ab82288
Version: webpack 4.47.0
Time: 6812ms
Built at: 09/11/2024 7:46:11 PM
           Asset      Size  Chunks                          Chunk Names
    admin-app.js   863 KiB       0  [emitted]        [big]  main
admin-app.js.map  3.09 MiB       0  [emitted] [dev]         main
Entrypoint main [big] = admin-app.js admin-app.js.map
 [44] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 472 bytes {0} [built]
 [52] ./src/data/images.json 22.5 KiB {0} [built]
 [73] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 497 bytes {0} [built]
[496] ./src/admin-app.js + 83 modules 357 KiB {0} [built]
      | ./src/admin-app.js 12.3 KiB [built]
      | ./src/data/audiencing.js 1.93 KiB [built]
      | ./src/eventBus.js 55 bytes [built]
      | ./src/utils/quill-links.js 4.99 KiB [built]
      | ./src/mixins/generate-id.js 205 bytes [built]
      | ./src/mixins/image-selector.js 565 bytes [built]
      | ./src/mixins/image-lookup.js 385 bytes [built]
      |     + 77 hidden modules
    + 715 hidden modules

WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
This can impact web performance.
Assets:
  admin-app.js (863 KiB)

WARNING in entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.
Entrypoints:
  main (863 KiB)
      admin-app.js


WARNING in webpack performance recommendations: 
You can limit the size of your bundles by using import() or require.ensure to lazy load some parts of your application.
For more info visit https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/

And its stuck here since 3-4 hours.
I have sufficient storage, memory available, also CPU utilization is 40%.
**
NOTE: I am new to VueJS but have idea of ReactJS.**
I tried changing node version, other versions of node directly throws error.

it's not stuck, it's done building and is watching the files, as the log indicates. See also the webpack config watch: true that makes this happen. you may want to modify the build process to fit your needs.
